# -1 Answer Checking Java

Tags: java, validation, if-statement

I'm trying to add a -1 answer check to my current Java but I've no idea how to start it. So when user input -1 it will immediately break from the loop.

So the output result should be as following,

Tax for $100000 is $100", Income, Tax
Enter income again, (-1 to stop the program):

Below is my current code, hope someone can help me with it :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question3 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        double Income, Tax = 0;
        char Answer;
        int counter = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter Income: $");
        Income = keyboard.nextDouble();

        if (Income <= 20000)
        {
            Tax = 0;
        }
        if (Income > 20000 && Income < 30000)
        {
            Tax = (Income - 20000) * 0.02;
        }
        else if (Income > 30000 && Income < 40000)
        {
            Tax = ((Income - 30000) * 0.035) + 200;
        }
        else if (Income > 40000 && Income < 80000)
        {
            Tax = ((Income - 40000) * 0.07) + 550;
        }
        else if (Income > 80000 && Income < 120000)
        {
            Tax = ((Income - 80000) * 0.115) + 3350;
        }
        else if (Income > 120000 && Income < 160000)
        {
            Tax = ((Income - 120000) * 0.15) + 7950;
        }
        else if (Income > 160000 && Income < 200000)
        {
            Tax = ((Income - 160000) * 0.18) + 13950;
        }
        else if (Income > 200000 && Income < 240000)
        {
            Tax = ((Income - 200000) * 0.19) + 21150;
        }
        else if (Income > 240000 && Income < 280000)
        {
            Tax = ((Income - 240000) * 0.195) + 28750;
        }
        else if (Income > 280000 && Income < 320000)
        {
            Tax = ((Income - 280000) * 0.20) + 36550;
        }
        else if (Income > 320000)
        {
            Tax = ((Income - 320000) * 0.22) + 44550;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println ("Invalid Input");
        }


        System.out.printf("Tax for $%.2f is $%.2f\n", Income, Tax);
        System.out.print("Enter income again, (-1 to stop the program): ");
        Answer = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to do your homework, so I will give you a clue.. what loop..

Comment: @diiN__________ This isn't javascript.

Comment: @some sorry, he irritated me with "my current Java Script".

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is no loop, although you should use a loop. You should just do this:

```
// if-else-if chain
if(Income == -1){
return;
}
```

If this is what you want, then when user enters -1 as Income, it should return void, which breaks the program.